# Value which is passed into function is not defined?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to build a simple todo app and I ran into an error.
I'm getting a text which is typed into input, assigning it to the item with innerText and adding the item to my list when the button is clicked.
But when I'm clicking the button I'm getting *text is not defined*

I'm a noob in javascript and not sure why this is happening and how to fix it so any help would be appreciated.

[This is the link to codepen with my code](https://codepen.io/Allan11/pen/GmpmLz)

```
document.getElementById('todo').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var value = document.getElementById('input-field').value;
  if (value) {
    //console.log(value)
    addItem(text)
  }
});

function addItem(text) {
  // reveal an input field
  var action = 1;
  if (action) {
    var input = document.getElementById('input-field');
    input.style.width = '0' ? '85%' : '0';
    action = 0;
  } else if (!action) {
    //create element and add it to the DOM
    var list = document.getElementById('list');
    var item = document.createElement('li');
    item.innerText = text;

    var btn = document.createElement('button');
    btn.classList.add('todo__btn');

    item.appendChild(btn);
    list.appendChild(item);

    action = 1;
  }

}
document.getElementById('add-item').addEventListener('click', addItem);
```

Comment: `addItem(value);` not `addItem(text);`. Your variable is called `value` not `text`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `action` is scoped inside the function, so it is always `1`
2. `addEventListener` calls `function(event)`, so `text` will be click event arguments, not text.
3. In `input.style.width = '0' ? '85%' : '0'` the conditional argument is `'0'`
4. `addItem(text)` in `document.getElementById('todo').addEventListener('click'...` is calling an undefined variable `text`, try `addItem(value)`;

Fixed:

```js
document.getElementById('todo').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var value = document.getElementById('input-field').value;
  if (value) {
    //console.log(value)
    addItem(value);
  }
});

var action = true;

function addItem(e) {
  var input = document.getElementById('input-field');
  // reveal an input field
  if (action) {

    input.style.width = '85%';
    action = false;
  } else if (!action) {
    //create element and add it to the DOM
    var item = document.createElement('li');
    item.classList.add('todo__btn');
    item.innerText = input.value;

    var btn = document.createElement('button');
    btn.classList.add('todo__list-item');

    item.appendChild(btn);
    
    var list = document.getElementById('list');
    list.appendChild(item);

    action = true;
  }

}
document.getElementById('add-item').addEventListener('click', addItem);
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,500,700");
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  background: #8e9eab;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #eef2f3, #8e9eab);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #eef2f3, #8e9eab);
}

.container {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.app {
  position: relative;
  background: white;
  width: 50%;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 15px auto;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.header {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: MediumSlateBlue;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
}

.todo {
  color: black;
}

.todo__list {
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.todo__list-item {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 10px 0;
  line-height: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ebebeb;
}

.todo__list-item:last-of-type {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.todo__btn {
  position: relative;
  appearance: none;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: none;
  background: none;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}

.unchecked {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  background-color: MediumSlateBlue;
  mask-image: url(/img/circle.svg);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

.checked {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  background-color: MediumSlateBlue;
  mask-image: url(/img/check.svg);
}

.form {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

.form__btn {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  appearance: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: MediumSlateBlue;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.form__btn svg {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin: -8px;
}

.form__reveal {
  width: 0;
  text-indent: 10px;
  transition: width 0.3s ease-in-out;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  appearance: none;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(44, 62, 80, 0.1);
  background: MediumSlateBlue;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.1em;
}

.form__reveal::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: white;
}

.complete {
  color: #9e9ea0;
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

.fill {
  fill: white;
}
```

```html
<section class="app">
  <header class="header">
    <h1 class="header__head">Today</h1>
  </header>
  <section class="todo" id="todo">
    <div class="container">
      <ul class="todo__list" id="list">
        <li class="todo__list-item">Reading Bukowski
          <button class="todo__btn unchecked"></button>
        </li>
        <li class="todo__list-item complete">Nor rrr
          <button class="todo__btn checked"></button>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <form class="form">
      <input class="form__reveal" id="input-field" placeholder="Enter a task">
      <button class="form__btn" id="add-item">
+
          </button>
    </form>
  </section>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is some problems with your code:

1. You are calling the function `addItem` using the wrong parameter (it should be `value` instead of `text` as `text` is `undefined` withing the callback of the event listener).
2. The `else if` in the `addItem` function is never enterd because the `if`'s condition is alwarys `true`.
3. The lase line is using `addItem` as the event listener, so when `#add-item` is clicked the function will be called, but the `text` argument will be the event.